# Problem to use my Callback function in using "For"?

Tags: node.js, function, for-loop, callback, explain

My code:

```
console.log('Start')
getMember((member) => { console.log(member) })
console.log('End')

function getMember(next) {
    for (let index = 0; index < 1000000000; index++) {
        // Simulation setTimeout()
    }
    next('In getMember')
}
```

> Return: 
> Start 
> In getMember 
> End

I thought I had the following result (see below) but it doesn't, can you explain me?

> Return: 
> Start 
> End
> In getMember

Thanks,

Yves

---

Comment: Asynchronous code in nodejs by itself is non-blocking.  That means it doesn't stop your `for` loop and wait for the async operation to finish.  If you show us the REAL asynchronous code, not some simulation, we can help you solve your real problem.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly the "for" instruction makes the code synchronous !?

Comment: I thought when I call a function with a "callback" argument it automatically makes it asynchronous!

Comment: Therefore, how can I know if a certain function or instruction handles asynchronous?
ex: the "for" instruction is blocking

Comment: Show some REAL asynchronous code and a real problem in your `for` loop and I'm happy to explain.  A comment that says "simulation" doesn't give us anything real to explain.  Theoretical questions don't work well here on stackoverflow because theoretical answers require like a chapter of a book to explain all the possibilities.  Questions that show your real code and describe your real problem often get solved right away because a quick code snippet with a little explanation can show you the way quickly.

Comment: Your understanding about `for` loop and callbacks and asynchronous seems flawed, but please show a REAL piece of asynchronous code you're attempting to use to solve a real problem and I can then explain more in relation to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log('Start')
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // setTimeout(() => { resolve('resolved') }, 2000);
        for (let index = 0; index < 1000000000; index++) { }
        resolve('resolved !');
    })
};

async function asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result);
}

asyncCall();

console.log('End');
```

> Return: 
> Start 
> calling 
> End
> resolved !

I have the impression that promises handle callbacks better !

Comment: In this example, the asynchronous seems to work because the output is:
Start
calling
End
resolved!

Comment: I replace my "setTimeout" with a "for" (simulation of the setTimeout) ok it's blocking but I have my "resolved !" after the "End" and this is not the case in my first example, Strange !

Comment: This does not demonstrate an asynchronous operation INSIDE a `for` loop which is the proposed issue.